# 'setcap' overwrites last capability. How do I set multiple capabilities?

Tags: capabilities, setcap

I want to give node.js the ability to listen on port 80, and shutdown the computer.  Initially I tried these two commands in sequence:

```
setcap cap_net_bind_service=+ep /usr/bin/nodejs
setcap cap_sys_boot=+ep /usr/bin/nodejs
```

Then my app was failing to bind to port 80.  I checked with getcap:

```
# getcap /usr/bin/nodejs
/usr/bin/nodejs = cap_sys_boot+ep
```

If I run setcap again for cap_net_bind_service:

```
# getcap /usr/bin/nodejs
/usr/bin/nodejs = cap_net_bind_service+ep
```

I don't see anything in the man page http://linux.die.net/man/8/setcap about setting multiple capabilities, and try some things in desperation:

```
# setcap cap_net_bind_service=+ep /usr/bin/nodejs cap_sys_boot=+ep /usr/bin/nodejs
# getcap /usr/bin/nodejs
/usr/bin/nodejs = cap_sys_boot+ep
# setcap cap_net_bind_service=+ep cap_sys_boot=+ep /usr/bin/nodejs
Failed to set capabilities on file `cap_sys_boot=+ep' (No such file or directory)
```

How do I set multiple capabilities?­­­­­­­

Answer (score 32, accepted):

And one last desperate syntax guess pays off:

```
# setcap cap_net_bind_service,cap_sys_boot=+ep /usr/bin/nodejs
# getcap /usr/bin/nodejs
/usr/bin/nodejs = cap_net_bind_service,cap_sys_boot+ep
```

Answer (score 1):

For anyone who arrived at this question: if you want to specify different actions for different capabilities, this is the syntax you need:

```bash
# this is for illustrative purposes only
# obviously it's not how you would formally define the syntax
setcap "<CAP_0,CAP_1,...><ACTIONS_A> <CAP_2,...><ACTION_B> ..."
```

So using OP's example, let's assume that you want to set `=+eip` for `cap_net_bind_service` instead of `=+ep`, this is what you would do:

```bash
setcap "cap_net_bind_service=+eip cap_sys_boot=+ep" /usr/bin/nodejs
```

---

More formally, each "capability description" as accepted by `setcap` is comprised of multiple space-separated "clauses", where each clause is in the form of `<CAP_NAME_LIST><OPS><FLAGS>` (an `<OPS><FLAGS>` pair is also referred to as an "action").

So if we take the aforementioned example:

`cap_net_bind_service=+eip cap_sys_boot=+ep`

Here `cap_net_bind_service=+eip` is the first clause, where `cap_net_bind_service` is the comma-separated list of capability names (only one item in this list), `=+` are the operators (reset then raise), and `eip` are the flags (effective, inheritable, and permitted). Similarly `cap_sys_boot=+ep` is the second clause etc.

---

If you want a detailed description of the full syntax, you should refer to the manual page of `cap_from_text`. Here's a [link](https://linux.die.net/man/3/cap_from_text) if you prefer reading from die.net.